# Inspect Elements of cache2k Cache when using it with Spring Boot and Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, cache2k

I am using cache2k with Spring Boot and Kotlin. I would like to inspect the stored elements (key-value pairs) in debug mode but I can't figure out how to do it. When I inspect the `SpringCache2kCache` or `HeapCache` object which I get when using `.nativeCache` I can't see the elements.

Here is the code I have. I can inspect the cache object(s) but I don't see the elements.

```
    @Test
    fun testCaching() {
        val result = client.getUserById(123456) // uses the cache to store the user object
        val cache: Cache? = cache[CachingConfig.USER_CACHE]
        val nativeCache: HeapCache<...,...> = cache[CachingConfig.USER_CACHE]?.nativeCache
        ...
    }
```

The caching functionality works as expected. I just want to inspect it to get a deeper understanding about how it works in detail.